# if cell D contain in "MSD__CMT_Change"then

Tags: vba, excel

what would the VBA code be to do the following.

```
if cell = MSD_CMT_CHANGE then  

    compare cell above it if equal "MSD_CHANGE" then 

        cell E1 = E2.
```

I have over 5000 rows of data.

Check image below for better explanatation.

[image: sheet]

Comment: Hi Mogli. Have you even tried to write the VBA code for your psuedo-code? This site is more geared towards "hey, I am having trouble figuring out how to do this exact thing in code, here is what I tried... " then "What's the code for this?" as shown in the www.stackoverlow.com/faq

Comment: @Mogli - are you looking to work through column D looking for MSD_CMT_CHANGE or is it simply just one cell (D2 in example) you want to run code for???

Comment: @Remnant I am looking through column D for `MSD_CMT_CHANGE`

Comment: @Scott Holtzman, I tried, I am not good at vba, and thanks your edit makes more sense.

Comment: `I tried` That is great! Show us what you tried, so we can tweak it to make it work. You'll learn way more that way :) It looks like Remnant has solved your riddle below, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Sub Test
    Dim rng as Range, cl as Range

    Set rng = Range("D2:D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    For each cl in rng
       If cl = "MSD_CMT_CHANGE" AND cl.Offset(-1, 0) = "MSD_CHANGE" Then
           cl.Offset(-1, 1) = cl.Offset(0, 1)
       End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for simple, easy good. The only edit I would recommend is changing `Range("D1").End(xlDown).Row` to `Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` to ensure capturing of the full data set, without the risk of coming across a random blank row in the middle, that may happen with `xlDown`

Comment: @Scott - Thanks for upvote. Agree your point about the hazard of random blanks. I'll update the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks alot that worked and thanks @ScottHoltzman I was going to ask about that. is there a way I can add another certeria in if cl = "MSD_STATUS_CHANGE then compare cell below if = "MSD_CHANGE" then ...

Comment: @Remnant if I accept answer will you let you still answer or edit your answer?

Comment: @Remnant code only works if I have no blank rows in between, I have many blank rows in between because I have empty rows it is like of like group by column A. like eg. in column A I have row 1 to 10 = book, row 11 blank, row 12 to 23 = cars, 24 blank, 25 to 29 = mouse. hope I am making sense.

Comment: may be I can replace blanks cells in column D = "---"

Comment: @Mogli. Remnant's edited code above should work just fine for blanks.

Comment: Yep, sorry for that it works, I forgot to replace MSD_CHANGE with actual text lol, thanks alot both of you, now i will try to edit this code by adding to compare with cell above condition.

Comment: How can I compare E & F in row 2 I tried by adding this ` If cl = "MSD_CMT_CHANGE" And c1.Offset(0, 2) = c1.Offset(0, 1)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Mogli - What error message do you get? Are you sure it is not a typo - your code above is using `c1` but should be `cl`?

Comment: @Remnant I don't even see error anymore but I did put the condition in there, even if condition is not met it still works. how can I add code to compare cell E & F in same row as MSD_CMT_CHANGE.

Comment: @Remnat, nevermind it works, sorry bug there is but in excel, I THINK, I have another check in tht, it checka if cell F1 = SYSTEM or "NO SYSTEM" it doesn't like space in between NO SYSTEM, if i remove space it works Thanks

Comment: @Remnant, in your code, how can I delete the current row after it does `cl.Offset(-1, 1) = cl.Offset(0, 1)` before it does to next loop thanks.

Comment: @Mogli - Try something like `cl.EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: @Remnant sorry, I need help again, how can I delete a row above cl, this is my what i tried `cl.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: @Remant nevermind I was able to figure it out, I have put code to delete cl.offset first then delete cl ... Thanks..

Comment: @Remnant I am sorry to bring this back up after long time, but do you know how to do this in SQL query?

Comment: @Mogli - Do you mean write SQL or execute an SQL command via VBA? If the latter it may be worth opening up a new post as this comment chain is quite long now and the solution you need is different.

Comment: I mean via SQL using built in funtion such as decode and lead, I was able to get one logic down. I will create new question, and will comment link here, donno if I can make it today or not.